# Connection refused [Errno 111] when typing swift start command

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

When I type the `swift stat` command, this error appears:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/AUTH_d17698cf7bbf4dcc8fc59ed6f7b48052 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1b0c2939a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

And when I type this command to see if there's a listen on port 8080, nothing appears:

```
netstat -tanpu | grep ":8080"
```

and when I try to restart or start the swift service with `service swift-proxy restart`, an error appears:

```
Assertion failed on job for swift-proxy.service.
```

Comment: I assume this has nothing to do with the programming language Swift

Comment: I already changed the tag from swift to openstack-swift

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Datacenter configuration problems are discussed in serverfault.com.

Comment: Obviously, Swift is not starting. I am sure that the error is more explicit than "assertion failed". In particular, the specific assertion that failed should be printed. If not, perhaps `systemctl status swift-proxy` tells you more, or `journalctl -u swift-proxy -e`. Also, have a look at the unit file to see which assertions are tested: `systemctl cat swift-proxy`.

Comment: systemctl status swift-proxy tells me  ""assertion failed" ur the right the swift is not starting that's the problem any ideas to how to solve the issue and start it ?

Comment: Does it not tell you which assertion failed? Have you checked what assertions are defined in the unit file?